# return value from aiohttp post method

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am currently working with the aiohttp post method. With `await post.read()` I get the return value when the method is executed. But now I have the problem that I want to get the return value as soon as the post is executed. This is not possible with `await post.read()`, because on the webinterface the uploaded file is still being processed. So how is it possible to intercept such a kind of intermediate steps?

```
async def post()
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    archive = "some file"
    url = "some url"
    post = await session.post(url, data=archive, ssl=False)
    await post.read() 
    await session.close()
asyncio.run(post())
```

Comment: if you get result from `POST` then it was executed. And if webinterface is still processing some data after uploading then it is not businnes of POST. It uploaded file so it made its job. Normally webinterface should gives unique number which you could use with another requests to check if file was processed. But all this depends on webpage - it may not have this functional. So your problem has nothing to do with POST but rather with functions on server. If it get file and doesn't give any information about processing then `POST` can't change it.

Comment: That's probably the problem and a good advice. So i created a task ```asyncio.create_task(current_step(url))``` with a function that check the webpage response. I think this is the best solution for my issue.